# JSTL comparing strings with <c:if>

Tags: jsp, jstl

The if condition is never evaluated as true even though strings are the same. one parameter is from the session and the other is from the url

```
<div>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Course</td>
        <td>Grade</td>
    </tr>
    <c:set var="param1" value="${param.crs}"/>
    <c:forEach var="course" items="${sessionScope.currentStudent.getGrades()}">
        <c:out value="${course.getCourseName()}"/>
        <c:out value="${course.getGrade()}"/>
        <br/><br/>
        <c:out value="${param1}"/>
        <c:if test="${param1} == ${course.getCourseName()}">
        <tr>
            <td><c:out value="${course.getCourseName()}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${course.getGrade()}"/></td>
        </tr>
        </c:if>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

this is the code from the jsp.it doesn't appear to be any other problem.i also tried with = or eq

Answer (score 0):

nevermind. i just figured it out.   "${param1==course.getCourseName()}